# Apresentar um EnumDropDownListFor conforme uma condição

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Como apresentar um `EnumDropDownListFor` conforme uma condição? Por exemplo, se o usuário desejar informar sua orientação sexual o *enum* é apresentado. Caso contrario não é apresentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
@if (UsuarioNaoQuerApresentarOrientacaoSexual)
{
    @Html.Hidden(model => model.OrientacaoSexual, OrientacaoSexual.NaoInformado)
}
else
{
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.OrientacaoSexual, ...)
}
```

Comment: Esse UsuarioNaoQuerApresentarOrientacaoSexual é um tipo bool ?

Comment: Sim, pode ser também uma condição que devolva `bool`.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo completo